# Dust.js @sep example not working

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I tried using Dust.js template engine with the first page `hello world` and it failed to use the `{@sep}` markings, the template was compiled and produced output, but not the commas `{@sep},{/sep}`

http://jsfiddle.net/t1qh9abw/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var template = "Dust does {#features}{name}{@sep},{/sep}{/features}!"

    var compiled = dust.compile(template, "test");
    dust.loadSource(compiled);

    dust.render("test", {
      features: [
        {name: "async"},
        {name: "helpers"},
        {name: "filters"},
        {name: "a little bit of logic"},
        {name: "and more"}
      ]
    },
    function (err, out) {
        document.getElementById('container').textContent = out;
    });
});
```

The `{@sep},{/sep}` does not seem to produce anything, the output is

`Dust does asynchelpersfiltersa little bit of logicand more!`

While the example output from the actual home page 
http://www.dustjs.com/ seems to be working just fine, which suggest there is something fishy in my own code or the version I am using.

Then I thought the CDN may be serving an outdated file, so I tried using directly the latest release from GitHub using rawgit.com link

`http://rawgit.com/linkedin/dustjs/master/dist/dust-full.js`

The example is here : http://jsfiddle.net/5apgp1sf/ and it still does not output the `@sep` tag contents.

What went wrong? I can't see the commas, so should I go shopping glasses or file a bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I will answer this question myself. I did some research on the Dustjs homepage and figured it out.

It was not obvious, that even if there were packages like

- dust-core
- dust-full

The *full package* does not seem to actually contain the `@sep`definition, even if that is the frontpage example.

So, importing the file `dust-helpers.js` solved this problem for me.

Comment: The difference between core and full is just the compiler.